# How to read in csv file to array in bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, csv

I have written the following code to read in my csv file (which has a fixed number of columns but not a fixed number of rows) into my script as an array. I need it to be a shell script.

```
usernames   x1    x2   x3  x4
username1,  5     5    4   2
username2,  6     3    2   0
username3,  8     4    9   3
```

My code

```
#!/bin/bash
set oldIFS = $IFS
set IFS=,
read -a line < something.csv
```

another option I have used is

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\t' reaad -r -a line
do 
echo $line
done < something.csv
```

for both I tried some test code to see what the size of the array line would be and I seem to be getting a size of 10 with the first one but the array only outputs username. For the second one, I seem to be getting a size of 0 but the array outputs the whole csv.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: read two times. with `,` and `white space`.

Comment: Note that there must not be any whitespace in variable assignments, so `set oldIFS = $IFS` should be `set oldIFS=$IFS`. Also, your sample data is a mixture of comma- and whitespace-separated fields. Is that how your input data is actually looking? If not, please provide an accurate example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using `AWK` with a regular expression in `FS` variable like this:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS=",?[ \t]*"; } { print $1,"|",$2,"|",$3,"|",$4,"|",$5; }'
```

or this

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS=",?[ \t]*"; OFS="|"; } { $1=$1; print $0; }'
```

(`$1=$1` is required to rebuild $0 with new OFS)