# How to get a csv file as an array in unix shell?

Tags: shell, unix, csv

Below is the script I'm using

```
#!/bin/bash

export IFS=","

cat ddd.csv
```

I need to get the contents of **ddd.csv** as an array.
I also need to convert that array in the form of a table with headers.

Please help,I'm really new to unix shell.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input, and exactly what you hope to do with it? Do you want an array where each item is one line of the CSV, or are you looking to read in multiple arrays, where each row from the CSV is returned as a single array? Or something else?

Comment: I need to compare the values of the mysql database with that of the csv array.How will i accomplish that?

Comment: **Example of the input** -> header1,header2,header3,
content1, content2, content3,
content1, content2, content3,
content1, content2, content3

Comment: When someone asks for additional information it is best to update your question rather than posting a comment (because the options for formatting things are much richer in the question).  For example, your comment appears to show a single row, but from the names you have used I am guessing it actually represents multiple rows.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290809/how-to-read-in-csv-file-to-array-in-bash-script

Comment: [edit] your question with the information you mentioned in comments. Otherwise, we are unlikely to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/shell-read-text-or-csv-file-and-extract.html) shows some tricks on how to extract CSV data in bash as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3
do
        echo $f1 $f2 $f3
done < ddd.csv
```

This should give you a table like output. Alternatively you can put the fields into an array or do whatever you like with them.