# how to convert from csv to array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, csv, ubuntu

I'm new on bash and I want to convert a csv file to different arrays. My csv has 6 lines with same number of columns each and I need to take lines 3,4,5 and 6 with all columns and make and array out of every line, any idea how can I do that?

My csv looks like:

1. A, B, C, ...
2. 1,        1,        1,...
3. 7,        23,       58,...
4. 8,        24,       59,...
5. 9,        25,       60,...
6. 10,       26,       61,...

And I want my output to look like:

array1=(7,23,58,...)

array2=(8,24,59,...)

array3=(9,25,60,...)

array4=(10,26,61,...)

Many thanks

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What is your field separator? `,` or `,` followed by a space? Is first column with 1,2,3,4,5,6 part of your file?

Comment: the field separator is just "," , and the first column it's not part of the file

Comment: It looks like you're on the way to do something inefficient or "dangerous". Can you explain what is your goal? Have you ever heard of awk? It may be just what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read in csv file to array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290809/how-to-read-in-csv-file-to-array-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: The script below will result in an extra empty array but it should do the job.*

Parsing `.csv` files with Bash is probably not the most efficient but there is a way to do it. Note that arrays in Bash are separated by `space`, not `,`.

In the example below, the input `.csv` file is `input.csv` and the output file is `output.txt`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
{
    read
    read
    var=0
    while IFS=, read -a arr
    do
        var=$((var+1))
        echo "array${var}=(${arr[@]})" >> output.txt
    done 
} < input.csv
```

*More explanation*
* The two lines of `read` is the key here: it reads the first two lines of your `.csv` input and then enters the loop, when it is going to start reading the third line.
* According to the documentation [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html), the `-a` flag **assigns the words read to sequential indices of the array variable ARRAY, starting at zero**.
* "@" is used to access all the values in the generated array resulting from `read -a`

*Edited my script based on @Poshi's suggestion. Script looks cleaner now.*

Comment: Take a look at `-e` parameter of `echo`. Also, `echo "array${var}=(${arr[*]})" >> output.txt` could simplify things quite a lot. This is assuming there are no spaces in the fields.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I will test that and update my script above once I am sure it works.